# take action when moving object reached the x, y coordinate in Lua

Tags: lua

There are 2 actions in my script

1. find the x1, y1 coordinate of ball
2. shoot the ball when it reaches the x, y coordinate

I have tested many times and there is no reaction when the object reached the x, y coordinate that I set in the script. Could someone please point out where the problems are. Thank you

```
function main()
    x1, y1 = findImageFuzzy("/mnt/sdcard/b1.bmp", 90);                          ---- Find Moving Object
        if getColor(368, 653) == 0xBB0011 and x1 == 368 and y1 == 653 then      ---- if moving object reach on this x, y coordinate 
            touchDown(0, 368, 653)                                              ---- shoot
            touchUp(0)          
        elseif getColor(352, 756) == 0xBB0011 and x1 == 352 and y1 == 756 then
            touchDown(0, 352, 756)
            touchUp(0)      
        elseif getColor(382, 468) == 0xBB0011 and x1 == 382 and y1 == 468 then
            touchDown(0, 382, 468)
            touchUp(0)              
        elseif getColor(361, 551) == 0xBB0011 and x1 == 361 and y1 == 551 then
            touchDown(0, 361, 551)
            touchUp(0)              
        elseif getColor(366, 467) == 0xBB0011 and x1 == 366 and y1 == 467 then
            touchDown(0, 366, 467)
            touchUp(0)              
        elseif getColor(352, 620) == 0xBB0011 and x1 == 352 and y1 == 620 then
            touchDown(0, 352, 620)
            touchUp(0)              
        end         
end
```

I know it might be too dumb to ask such stupid questions, but for a non-computering person, your help would gain me huge improvement.

Comment: just out of curiosity, which engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ball moves more than one pixel per frame, it probably does not match those exact coordinates on any given frame. Instead of `==`, use `<=` or `>=`.